# Longtable with label producing trailing lines

Tags: longtable, labels

I have a `longtable` that takes up about 4 pages, that is inside a `center`. When I use a `\label` on the `longtable`, I'm getting weird extra lines after the table, depending on where I place the `\label`. If it goes before `\end{longtable}` (as in the following code block), these extra vertical lines appear below the first column.

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{||c|c|c|c|c||}
        \caption{My Caption}\\*
        \hline
        \hline
        %Stuff
        5 & Item1 & Item2 & Item3  & Item4 \\
        \hline
        \hline
        \label{myLabel}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Interestingly, if the `\label` comes outside of the `\end{longtable}`, then the lines don't appear, but then the labelling doesn't work properly.

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{||c|c|c|c|c||}
        \caption{My Caption}\\*
        \hline
        \hline
        %Stuff
        5 & Item1 & Item2 & Item3  & Item4 \\
        \hline
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
    \label{myLabel}
\end{center}
```

[image]

What can be done to get rid of these extra lines, but get the labelling working properly?

Comment: `\label` without `\caption` is useless, so in both cases, you're doing it wrong ;-)  Omit it and there is no issue. And `longtable` is centered anyway, so `\begin{center}...\end{center}` is useless as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry, I have captions, I just didn't include it in the code blocks. They're edited in.

Comment: Then add it to the code and provide a compilable document, not just fragments only. And use either `\endfirsthead` etc. to make a clear separation between table head (or foot) and your caption

Comment: it is useless putting `longtable` into a `center`  (or `raggedright` etc) it just adds spurious vertical space and has no affect at all on its horizontal position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{||c|c|c|c|c||}
\caption{ lalalala }
        \label{myLabel}             \\
\hline
5 & Item1 & Item2 & Item3  & Item4  \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

i.e. move `label` immediately after `caption`.

[image]